# Load a dataset with Pytorch's Dataloader and cache the dataset with multiple workers

Tags: pytorch, multiprocessing, pytorch-dataloader

I want to load a dataset with [Pytorch's Dataset and Dataloader classes](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#module-torch.utils.data). I have the dataset in multiple very big [npz files](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) and each npz file contains several numpy arrays that will be the input of the model.

My problem is that accessing each numpy array is very time consuming as you not only have to load the npz file, but also access a single numpy inside that npz file. I was wondering if there is a good way to cache the already loaded npz files so that, when I have to access other numpy array that is contained in a npz file that has already been accessed, I don't have to load it again. Right now I am loading them in a dictionary and, in case the size of the dictionary is too big (maximum size of the cache), I delete some of the cached npz. My biggest concern with this is what happens when using multiple workers (`num_workers > 1`). Is there a way to control these "common" resources for all the workers that load the dataset.

My code is as follows:

```py
class MyDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, labels_path: str, volumes_path: str,
                 input_shape: Tuple[int, int, int] = (115, 70, 76),
                 max_cache_size=5000000000, check_free_cache_n=10):
        """ Initializer

        Args:
            labels_path: List with the path of the csvs with the labels
            volumes_path: List with the paths with the numpy with the teeth
            input_shape: Shape of the input of the model
            max_cache_size: Max size of the cache in bytes
            check_free_cache_n: Checks every n iterations if the cache should be cleared
        """
        self.labels_path = labels_path
        self.volumes_path = volumes_path
        self.input_shape = input_shape
        self.cache = {}
        self.max_cache_size = max_cache_size
        self.count_since_free_cache = 0
        self.check_free_cache_n = check_free_cache_n

        # Load the table with the labels
        df = pd.DataFrame(...load the dataset...) # The dataset has a column with the path of the file and n columns with the prediction. In addition there is a single row per single numpy (each npz contains several np)
        self.labels_df = df

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # Get the item
        row = self.labels_df.iloc[index]
        path = row["path"]  # Each row represents a single numpy and it has associated a path to its corresponding npz file (this npz file contains multiple numpy)
        vol_id = str(row["vol_id"])  # ID that represents an unique numpy array

        if path in self.cache.keys():
            vol = self.cache[path]["vol"][vol_id]
            self.cache[path]["last_read"] = time.time()
        else:
            volumes = np.load(path)
            self.cache[path] = {
                "vol": {},
                "last_read": time.time()
            }
            total_size = 0
            # Load all the volumes
            for vol_id, vol_np in volumes.items():
                # Format the loaded numpy
                vol_np = resize(vol_np, self.input_shape, preserve_range=True)
                vol_np = np.expand_dims(vol_np, axis=0)

                # Save the numpy
                self.cache[path]["vol"][vol_id] = vol_np
                total_size += vol_np.nbytes

            self.cache[path]["size"] = total_size

            # Get the actual volume of the current tooth
            vol = self.cache[path]["vol"][vol_id]

        # Clear cache
        if self.count_since_free_cache > self.check_free_cache_n:
            self.clear_cache()
            self.count_since_free_cache = 0
        self.count_since_free_cache += 1

        # Return 
        x = torch.from_numpy(vol)
        y = row[[...colnames...]]

        return x, y

    def cache_size(self):
        """
        To calculate the size of the cache
        """
        return sum([x["size"] for x in self.cache.values()])

    def clear_cache(self):
        """
        To clear the cache if it is too big
        """
        while self.cache_size() > self.max_cache_size:
            it_to_delete = min(self.cache.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["last_read"])
            del self.cache[it_to_delete[0]]

    # we can call len(dataset) to return the size
    def __len__(self):
        return self.labels_df.shape[0]
```

How should I manage the way the workers access to the dictionary `self.cache` so there are no problems when sharing this same object?